# Why should I separate internal logic of a public asynchronous method into a private method?

Tags: c#

I keep seeing code like this in the same class, I cant think of a reason to separate out a sequential private method. Anyone else can give a good reason?

```
 public Task<List<myObject>> GetObjectsAsync(object param)
    {
        try
        {
            return Task.Run(() => GetObject(param));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log error
        }
    }
```

and a private sequential method that accompanies it:

```
private List<myObject> GetObject(object param))
    {
        return _dLayer.GetObject(param));
    }
```

Comment: The reason why people hide it is simply because they do not want that method to be accessed directly. Rather, it has to be accessed asynchronously thru GetObjectAsync(). Unless you want to allow other parts of the code to access GetObject() synchronously and blocking call, then you can expose it to public.

Comment: Opinion: Unless you have to satisfy an interface you cannot change you shouldn't artificially create async wrapper for synchronous code, the caller can do that just as easily as you can and you've made life harder for the programmer who wants to call this in a synchronous context. If you have both async and non-async versions of a method, expose both.

Comment: That catch block won't catch database exceptions, only if the task is awaited using `return await Task.Run(() => GetObject(param));` Otherwise it should be moved to the calling method.

Comment: Yeah, that try/catch is messed up. It's not going to catch anything interesting.

Comment: Thanks guys for the responses, all very good!

Comment: Other point: if the `Task.Run` is solely their to satisfy the inteface for the purpose of introducing real asyn calls to the db later you could also use `return Task.FromResult(GetObject(param));` and avoid the overhead of `Task.Run`. See also http://www.ben-morris.com/why-you-shouldnt-create-asynchronous-wrappers-with-task-run/ and https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html

Comment: @Peter Bons, this is great, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always good to separate logical blocks -- however small they are -- into separate methods.  [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is as applicable widely -- such as with separate assemblies, namespaces, and classes -- as it is narrowly, as with methods and logical blocks of related behavior.  In this way, it becomes clear and natural to see where you can refactor your code into different classes to follow the "S" in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) -- single responsibility principle.

Keeping method sizes small is also important as it improves readability and re-useability.

I'm pretty sure this is why the code is written as such in your case.

Comment: Yes, that might be the case, make the synchronous method simpler to write and don't mix the complexities of the async exposure with the synchronous method.

Comment: Or better yet implement this in real threadless async. Sure you have less code reuse, but you get much better performance. We aren't java programmers here.

Comment: @Aron -- not really better performance I think, but definitely improved scalability.